# Accessing relationship tables data in rails (using has_many :through)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It is my first question, but I have yet to find an answer, so I hope it doesn't violate any rule.

I have a problem with a seemingly simple rails issue. I have taken the time to read about relationship models in rails (has_many :through) and came upon this example:

[Exemplary model relations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pTsV.png)

In my model, I have Anthology (phyisicians), Poem(patients), and an anthology_poem relationship model (appointments). In may relationship table, I have a column, order, that indicates the position of a specific poem in a specific anthology.

The question is - How do I address said "order" column? How do I update it/read it? I imagine something like:

```
book.poems.first.order
```

which obviously doesn't work.

I'd like to be able to do it without too much hacking, because I fell in love with how simply rails handled the rest of the stuff.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post your model code for these as they are?

Comment: You should remove `first` so it reads `book.poems.order`. If you have `first` it will only return one

Comment: @Dawcars He is trying to reach a column called `order` not to actually order the items.

Comment: Ah, ok. I misread it.

Comment: what error do you get when you try to run `Book.last.poems.first.order` on your rails console ?

Comment: Something similar to "unable to access property " order" no such property is found" will be able to update later when I get to my station. Also, tried changing it to poem_order so it won't interfere with the function; didn't change anything.

Comment: Yes, it says "nomethod error: Undefined method 'order' for #<Poem:0x005669f8630300>"

Answer (score -1):

If you want to access your relationship model attribute you should call it on that model:

```
Appointment.where(physician: physician).pluck(:order)
```